# How to make dummy context when testing graphql resolvers?

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I want to test some graphql mutations. but I am not sure what to give as context while writing test. for example, I want to call createPost mutation:

```
it('admin should create a post', async () => {
    await createPost(
      null,
      {
        title: 'How to write a blog post',
        body: 'lorem ipsum dollar emmet',
        published: true,
      },
      dummyContext
    ).should.be.fulfilled;
  });
```

here as a dummyContext I am using this:

```
  const dummyContext = {
    request: { get: () => token },
  };
```

but, it is not working. Inside `createPost` mutation `logincheker` method is called:

```
export async function loginChecker({ request }) {
  const Authorization = request.get('Authorization');
  if (Authorization) {
    const token = Authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
    const userInJwt = jwtValidator(token);
    const user = await prisma.user.findOne({ where: { id: userInJwt.id } });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('Not Authorized');
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

and I am getting this error while running the test cases

`AssertionError: expected promise to be fulfilled but it was rejected with 'TypeError: Authorization.replace is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Integrations tests, you do not need to mock the Context. You can directly run the server against an actual database as I have created [here](https://github.com/ryands17/nexus-auth/). In the `__tests__` folder, I have run it against the actual server and so you don't need to mock the Context and can directly call the API against the DB.